# Soundcloud user favorites endpoint removed?

Tags: soundcloud

I have been using the Soundcloud favorites endpoint `api.soundcloud.com/users/${USER_ID}/favorites` for the past few months and since yesterday it has been returning 404 with username in ID field or a max of 35 tracks with no next_href returned in the response.

For example a request with "domdolla" in USER_ID field will return 404, 
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/domdolla/favorites?linked_partitioning=1&offset=0&limit=200&client_id=XXXXXXXXXX

and a request with domdolla's user_id "627109" returns a collection of 32 tracks and no next_href.
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/627109/favorites?linked_partitioning=1&offset=0&limit=200&client_id=XXXXXXXXXX

However, if you retrieve domdolla's profile, it shows that he has 1082 public_favorites_count:
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/domdolla?client_id=XXXXXXXXXX

This endpoint is still documented in the Soundcloud HTTP API Reference here:
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users

Comment: Hi @ftw, this question should be pointed to Soundcloud. Stack overflow is about question on programming.

Answer (score 0):

They changed the API without updating the Docs.
The new endpoint is:

```
https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/{ID}/track_likes
```

This returns a list of "Likes".

The new api-v2 also already works with the resolve endpoint.

Comment: Could use a free tool like https://apipatrol.tech so you can prepare for it appropriately and get a notification in time.